# How to target a certain part of a string held within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

**This query runs and multiple results are stored in the id called "category"**

```
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var friends = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            friends.push({
                imageURL: results[i].get('Global_Badges_img'),
                //friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                badgename: results[i].get('BadgeName'),
                category: results[i].get('category'),

            });
        }

        _.each(friends, function(item) {
            var wrapper = $('<div></div>');
            wrapper.append('<img class="images BadgeImgOutline responsive-image" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />'+ '<br>');
            wrapper.append('<div class="tag badgelabel" >'+ item.badgename + '</div>'+ '<br>');
            wrapper.append('<div id="category" class="tag categorylabel" >'+ item.category + '</div>'+ '<br>'+ '<br>'   );


            $('#container').append(wrapper);
        });
```

Further in my code I'm using `categorySelected = $('div#category.tag.categorylabel').text();` to recall this data. However I only want the record that is stored in `item.category`At the moment I'm getting all records back in a text string.

How do I target item.category only?

Comment: ids should be unique. for one, your creating multiple divs with the same id, "category"

Comment: You have `category` ID repeating multiple times... ID's **must** be unique

Comment: @intothev01d ok, how do I address this? move the id out of the wrapper.append('<div id="category" class="tag categorylabel" >'+ item.category + '</div>'+ '<br>'+ '<br>'   ); line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `categorySelected =  $('#badgeselect .categorylabel').text();`

By taking the data from #badgeSelect it meant that the only data being available was that shown shown in the text box, instead of '#category'that returned all results.

The it was simply targeting the text correctly with the change to the var categorySelected